# What's the state of PDF/VT

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am interested in using PDF/VT but it seems all the info available is a couple of years out of date and it is as though it has just not gone anywhere since 2012.

Is this still a viable format for VDP and if so, as a developer how can I get to play around with it.
 The only vendor I can see that produces a PDF/VT SDK is PDFlib and they are not cheap.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks
Kieran

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of good information here https://www.pdfa.org/working-group/pdfvt-competence-center/

As for libraries, since PDF/VT builds on PDF and PDF/X, any library that can create and manipulate PDF at the COS level can work with PDF/VT even if they don't have dedicated classes to do so.

Answer (score 0):

[www.podi.org](http://www.podi.org), PPML seems dead, renderx.com seems dead, any open-source solutions I've looked for seem non existant.

The closest I've found is:
https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/
https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/pdfx.html

You might be able to play around with.